# How to improve this code of query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

This is what my employee use

```
var client = new MongoClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MongoDbServer"]);
var server = client.GetServer();
MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("Edbert");
var collection = db.GetCollection("testInstagram");

var query = Query.And(Query.Not(Query.Or(Query.Size("PossibleInstagramIDs", 1), Query.Size("PossibleInstagramIDs", 0))),Query.EQ("InstagramID",BsonNull.Value));
```

I think this part is ugly:

```
var query = Query.And(Query.Not(Query.Or(Query.Size("PossibleInstagramIDs", 1), Query.Size("PossibleInstagramIDs", 0))),Query.EQ("InstagramID",BsonNull.Value));
```

What he tries to do is to set the query to return true if size of PossibleInstagramIDs are bigger than 1.

What should he have done?

Comment: What does a document in the testInstagram collection look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the collection strongly typed by creating a `TestInstagram` class and then use [LINQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/).

Your `TestInstagram` class will look something like this:

```
public class TestInstagram
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> PossibleInstagramIDs { get; set; }
    public int InstagramID { get; set; }
}
```

And this will allow you to simply query as follows:

```
var collection = _mongoDatabase.GetCollection<TestInstagram>("testInstagram");
collection.AsQueryable().Where(ti => ti.PossibleInstagramIDs.Count() > 1 && ti.InstagramID == null);
```